# How to handle click on details (and navigate back on list) with infinite list item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have an infinite scroll which displays items
When I click on one item it opens the detail page
When I go back to the infinite scroll/list page I need to go back to the item I just clicked on, not to the top
How can I do that ?

Few ideas: 
Should I use an anchor link or some equivalent to choose the item I want to go back to ? 
Should I display the detail page on top of the list ?

Some details: 
The infinite scroll is paged and can received thousands of items
I'm working with ReactJS

Thank you !

Comment: Please be aware you always need to share a bit of code alongside your question, to make it more clear. See more details here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function, which achieve exactly what you want. Let’s say all of your items are identified by an unique id :

*rendered HTML*

```html
<div id="container">
  . . .
  <element id="1897">

  </element>
</div>
```

And your list is at `http://localhost:3001/my_url/list`. Clicking on your element brings you to the following address : `http://localhost:3001/mu_url/item/1897`.

Then, inside your element model, your link to go back to the main page should look something like this :

*item.jsx*

```
<Link
  . . .
  to={{
    pathname: `/my_url/list?lastPosition=${this.state.id}`
  }}
>
```

Notice that we added an **URL parameter** on our back button. Replace `this.state.id` with the reference to your current item id, if it isn’t here. Then, in your main component, you can add the following :

*container.jsx*

```
import React from ‘react’;
. . .

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {. . .}

  // React function that trigger once your component is mounted
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const lastPosition = url.searchParams.get(‘lastPosition’);

    if (lastPosition && element) {
      const element = document.querySelector(`#${lastPosition}`);
      element.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }

  . . .

  render() {
    . . .
  }
}
```

Thus, if an element id is given as an URL parameter AND an element is find with id matching this parameter, your window with automatically scroll to it. Plus, this allow you to send the link to other people, which will not have to scroll to find the item.